# Web architecture with c++ backend in Linux best way ?

Tags: c++, architecture, web

I have php front end that render the GUI ,
 from there I like to use c++ engine in the backend that gets the users request with data xml structures this c++ engine is responsible to   process the data and store it in the DB or files and return the response to the user
now , my front end is lighthttpd working great , in the back end I want to avoid to write the c/c++ daemon I like to use something that is well establish in the industry , which server shell I use to host my c++ back end code?
also what is the best way to establish connection between php and back end server ? sockets? Php sockets ?

Comment: For the last question - I suggest to try ZeroMQ for connection between frontend and backend server(s). It will also simplify architecture of your backend server and allow to scale it easier.

Comment: It should be orthogonal to your logic: ZeroMQ is a messaging library in C with bindings to all popular languages - just check http://www.zeromq.org/ and the guide: http://zguide.zeromq.org/

Comment: PHP binding is actively maintained, see http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:php

Comment: is it like http://gearman.org ?

Comment: no, but you could build something like gearman using zeromq - see examples in the guide